# Perceptual loss for image sequences in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, neural-network, loss-function

I want to implement perceptual loss for sequential image data of the shape [batch_size, sequence_length, height, width, channels]

The predictions of my model also have the same shape as the input.
My problem is, that I'm not able to properly feed in my predictions to the VGG16 in order to calculate the loss.

---

Firstly, I build my vgg as follows:

```
def build_vgg_model(self, weights="imagenet"):

    # Input image to extract features from
    img = Input(shape=(self.img_rows, self.img_cols, 3))

    # Mean center and rescale by variance as in PyTorch
    processed = Lambda(lambda x: (x - self.mean) / self.std)(img)

    # If inference only, just return empty model
    if self.inference_only:
        model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=[img for _ in range(len(self.vgg_layers))])
        model.trainable = False
        model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
        return model

    # Get the vgg network from Keras applications
    if weights in ['imagenet', None]:
        vgg = VGG16(weights=weights, include_top=False)
        # model = Model(inputs=base_model.input, outputs=base_model.get_layer('block4_pool').output)
    else:
        vgg = VGG16(weights=None, include_top=False)
        vgg.load_weights(weights, by_name=True)

    # Output the first three pooling layers
    vgg.outputs = [vgg.layers[i].output for i in self.vgg_layers]

    # Create model and compile
    model = Model(inputs=img, outputs=vgg(processed))
    model.trainable = False

    return model
```

Then I define my loss function:

```
def total_loss(self, mask):
    def loss(y_true, y_pred):
        # Compute predicted image with non-hole pixels set to ground truth
        y_comp = mask * y_true + (1 - mask) * y_pred

        # Compute the vgg features.
        if self.vgg_device:
            with tf.device(self.vgg_device):
                vgg_out = self.vgg(y_pred)
                vgg_gt = self.vgg(y_true)
                vgg_comp = self.vgg(y_comp)
        else:
            vgg_out = self.vgg(y_pred)
            vgg_gt = self.vgg(y_true)
            vgg_comp = self.vgg(y_comp)

        # Compute loss components
        l1 = self.loss_valid(mask, y_true, y_pred)
        l2 = self.loss_hole(mask, y_true, y_pred)
        l3 = self.loss_perceptual(vgg_out, vgg_gt, vgg_comp)

        # Return loss function
        return l1 + 6 * l2 + 0.05 * l3
    return loss

def loss_perceptual(self, vgg_out, vgg_gt, vgg_comp):
    loss = 0
    for o, c, g in zip(vgg_out, vgg_comp, vgg_gt):
        loss += self.l1(o, g) + self.l1(c, g)
    return loss
```

If I now run my code, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convlstm_main.py", line 51, in <module>
    model = ConvLSTM(64, 64, 3, 5)
  File "/mnt/workspace/lm78463/RecurrentDiFoRem/src/model/conv_lstm.py", line 40, in __init__
    self.model = self.compile()
  File "/mnt/workspace/lm78463/RecurrentDiFoRem/src/model/conv_lstm.py", line 116, in compile
    self.model.compile(loss=self.loss_total, optimizer='adadelta')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 229, in compile
    self.total_loss = self._prepare_total_loss(masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 692, in _prepare_total_loss
    y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=sample_weight)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 71, in __call__
    losses = self.call(y_true, y_pred)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 132, in call
    return self.fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
  File "/mnt/workspace/lm78463/RecurrentDiFoRem/src/model/conv_lstm.py", line 180, in loss_total
    vgg_gts = self.vgg(y_trues)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 489, in __call__
    output = self.call(inputs, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 583, in call
    output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 740, in run_internal_graph
    layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 583, in call
    output_tensors, _, _ = self.run_internal_graph(inputs, masks)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/engine/network.py", line 740, in run_internal_graph
    layer.call(computed_tensor, **kwargs))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/layers/convolutional.py", line 171, in call
    dilation_rate=self.dilation_rate)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 3717, in conv2d
    **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 917, in convolution
    name=name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 979, in convolution_internal
    strides = _get_sequence(strides, n, channel_index, "strides")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/nn_ops.py", line 74, in _get_sequence
    name, n, n + 2, current_n))
ValueError: strides should be of length 1, 3 or 5 but was 2
```